# How to close a sub program that won't exit (paused)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I downloaded a .exe program, I'd like run it with my program. The problem is, it won't exit itself.

Main.bat:

```
@echo off & cd/d %~dp0
start "" "K:\Doc\MyProgram.exe"
start "" "K:\Doc\DownloadedProgram.exe"
echo Do some work
exit
```

The problem is, the `DownloadedProgram.exe` have a bad design that it is a command-line application but after its work down, it says `done...press any key to exit.` instead of exit itself. Then when the `Main.bat` runs to `exit`, there's still a command window opened shows press any key blah blah.

Question: how can I run `Main.bat` and let it handle all the sub-apllications, when `Main.bat` exit, close any sub-application window automatically?

Comment: Have you tried `start "" "cmd /C K:\Doc\DownloadedProgram.exe"`?

Comment: Have you tried `<nul "K:\Doc\DownloadedProgram.exe"` or `echo/|"K:\Doc\DownloadedProgram.exe"`? (Don't if the .exe expects some input)

Comment: Also try `<nul start "" /b "K:\Doc\DownloadedProgram.exe"`. This avoids waiting for the program to exit (`start`), but without allocating a new console (`/b`), and redirects its standard input to the NUL device (`<nul`) to prevent reading from console input.

Comment: @eryksun This is the only solution that works, the `DownloadedProgram.exe` now print its log in the `Main.bat` window and exit itself no matter what it display when work done, thanks!